# Windows CMD %time% giving same time when used with & operators

Tags: cmd

I am using the following code to benchmark my script.

```
C:\Users\blueray>echo %time% & timeout /t 5 & echo %time%
```

Output

```
13:44:44.64
... after 5 seconds
13:44:44.64
```

I was expecting to have a 5 second increment when I echo %time% for the second time. 
What is the problem here and what is the solution?

Comment: Take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows command interpreter first preprocesses/parses the entire command line before execution. During this preprocessing all environment variable references in the form `%variable%` are expanded so that in your case the command line really executed is:

```
echo 13:44:44.64   & timeout /t 5   & echo 13:44:44.64
```

It is necessary to force a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) of the environment variables.

Usually delayed expansion is used in a batch file like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !TIME! & timeout /t 5 & echo !TIME!
endlocal
```

Or on specifying executable **TIMEOUT** with fully qualified file name and using immediate environment variable expansion on first `TIME` reference while using delayed expansion on second `TIME` reference:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %TIME% & %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /t 5 & echo !TIME!
endlocal
```

But there is a second method to get a delayed environment variable expansion in a batch file by using the command **CALL**.

```
echo %TIME% & %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /t 5 & call echo %%TIME%%
```

This command line in batch file results in executing finally the command line:

```
echo 13:44:44.64   & C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 5   & call echo %TIME%
```

The command **CALL** results in a second parsing of `echo %TIME%` before executing second **ECHO** resulting in getting output time about 5 seconds later than first time output.

In a command prompt window a different command line is required due to different interpreting of `%` in comparison to batch file processing.

```
echo %TIME% & timeout /t 5 & call echo ^%TIME^%
```

The percent sign characters are escaped with caret character `^` to be first interpreted as literal characters to finally  execute `call echo %TIME%`. In real it is enough to escape just second `%` while escaping just first `%` has not the wanted effect on time output. So working in a command prompt window as expected is also:

```
echo %TIME% & timeout /t 5 & call echo %TIME^%
```

But not working as expected in a command prompt window is:

```
echo %TIME% & timeout /t 5 & call echo ^%TIME%
```

Comment: The code works fine but I did not understand the last part. Why ^%TIME^% and %TIME^% works but ^%TIME% dont

Comment: @blueray I asked that myself too. I don't have a real explanation. I think the character `^` is simply just ignored and removed from command line by `cmd.exe` __after__ expanding the environment variable references according to answer on [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) So `^%TIME%` does not work because `^` is in real ignored because not really escaping `%` and so `%TIME%` is expanded first. Later `^` is removed from the command line. On usage of `%TIME^%` the environment variable expansion first fails.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround

```
(for /F "delims=" %x in ('echo ^%time^%') do echo %x )& timeout /t 2 &(for /F "delims=" %x in ('echo ^%time^%') do echo %x)
```

Comment: Running each `echo %time%` in a background command process started by __FOR__ using `cmd.exe /C`, capturing their outputs by __FOR__ and output the captured time output in current command process seems to be a quite difficult to use and understand workaround although working fine. There are easier solutions as I wrote in my answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Once the command line is read, `%time%` is changed to its value and then the command is executed.

> All env args %arg% change before command line execution.

In script: 
When the script is read it executes line after line. In that case your value will be different.